# Visual selection on variable line lengths

Tags: visual-mode

Suppose we have something like,

```
here is some text.
here is some more text.
here is.
here is some.
```

Starting with `gg 0`, how do I do something like `v t. 4j` so that I can replace text up to a `.` on each line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is **to replace** the text, not **select** it

```
1,4normal! ct.Whatever
```

Comment: Suppose I want to copy the text. Then `1,4normal! yt.` just copies the last line (well, I guess it copies each line 1 through 4, but doesn't store them as it would when yanking a visual block). The reason I was trying to select is so that I know what I am operating on.

Comment: @algae Vim doesn't support arbitrary visual selection. You can search for some "crutch"-plugin (vim-multiple-cursors or whatever they call it).

Comment: Thanks. Strange you can't copy it without visual selection though.

Comment: @algae Why not? `1,4normal! "Ayt.`

Comment: Okay, but no new lines.

Comment: @algae You must reset register before adding text to it. If it is set to "char" type then it will retain "char" type. And if it is set "line" type then there'll be the newlines.